# Wi-Fi only works after waking MacBookPro7,1 from sleep

Tags: wireless, suspend, broadcom, macbook-pro, 17.04

Been having some issues with the STA drivers from `bcrmwl-kernel-source`. While the drivers do function, they only seem to function after putting the laptop to sleep, by either closing the lid, or manually putting it to sleep, and waking it up. The laptop here is a MacBookPro7,1 (Mid 2010 13-inch MacBook Pro), running Ubuntu 17.04.

While the issue isn't bad enough to deter me from using the laptop, it is not an elegant solution, and I believe that there can be a solution found somewhere.

For reference, here are the outputs from the Wireless Info script for both before and after:
[before](https://pastebin.com/BkEi5h2E), [after](https://pastebin.com/TYNevP17). Hopefully these are of some use. If you need additional information about the computer, I will be happy to answer.

Comment: Chili555 will be delighted that you actually ran the script instead of ignoring that little popup like most people do :)

Comment: Hibernate/Suspend is handled by the `pm-utils` package. Read `man pm-action` to see which scripts are run when. One of them fixes your WiFi.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you mean when you said "Read `man pm-action`?" I don't know what to do. If you meant running that in the Terminal, it returns `No manual entry for pm-action`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Here's what I did to solve it:

1. Went to `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/` and looked for a script related to wireless or networking; there I found 60_spa_suplicant.
2. Copied that script into `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d`.
3. Modify this copied script (in power.d), removing the conditionals and keeping the instructions of what happens on wake-up. In my case, there was a CASE statement, so I removed all its lines except for **"$WPACLI resume"**.

By the way, I'm running Xubuntu 18.04 on my mid-2010 Macbook Pro.

Comment: Does not effect me but +1 for great idea.

Comment: It works. Note that the CASE statement begins with the keyword `case` and ends with the keyword `esac`. These two keywords, and all the content between them should be removed, except `$WPACLI resume`.